# What seems to be the minors of the Adjugate matrix $\text{adj}(A)$ of a square matrix $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, laplace-expansion

It is by definition that entries of the adjugate matrix $\text{adj}(A)$ are the corresponding $(n-1)$-minors of $A$ (up to a sign). What can we say about the $k$-minor of $\text{adj}(A)$ in relation to minors of $A$?

I have tried some cases starting from the definition of determinant (just like the proof of the Laplace expansion), but so far no luck. But I guess it is some kind of complementary minor in $A$.

Answer (score 4):

Never mind...I find this Jacobi's theorem from [Prasolov's (yes...every time...) book *Problems and theorems in linear algebra*](http://www2.math.su.se/~mleites/books/prasolov-1994-problems.pdf):
[image]

General case follows immediately from permutating the rows and columns.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying what $(-1)^{\sigma}$ means? I am confused because $\sigma$  is a matrix.

Comment: @mzp It is simply the signature of the permutation $\sigma$. $\sigma$ is not a matrix...Go read Prasolov's Problems and theorems in linear algebra.