# Principal Minors of $B(AB)^{-1}A$ and Cauchy-Binet Terms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I am looking for a proof for the following conjecture. I think the result follows from applying a [generalization of the Cauchy-Binet formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula#Generalization) to the matrix $\mathbf{M}$ defined bellow. I've tested it as much as I could using Mathematica and am convinced it is true, but I haven't been able to prove it. Any help will be much appreciated.

---

**Setup**

Suppose $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are $(n \times m)$ and $(m \times n)$ matrices respectively, with $n<m$ and $\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{A})=\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{B})=n$.

Let $K \equiv \{1,\dots,m\}$, $\mathbf{X}_{k}$ denote the matrix $\mathbf{X}$ keeping only columns and rows in $k$, $\mathbf{X}_{rk}$ denote the matrix $\mathbf{X}$ keeping only rows in $k$, and $\mathbf{X}_{ck}$ denote the matrix $\mathbf{X}$ keeping only columns in $k$. Also, for any $k \subset K$, let $K_n$ be the set of subsets of $K$ with $n$ elements.

Then, using the Cauchy-Binet formula, the determinant of the matrix $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}$, denoted by $\Delta$, can be written as

$$\Delta \equiv \det(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}) = \sum_{k\in K_n}{\det(\mathbf{A}_{ck})\det(\mathbf{B}_{rk})}. $$

Denote each element of this sum by

$$ d_k \equiv \det(\mathbf{A}_{ck})\det(\mathbf{B}_{rk}), \;\;\;\;\text{for all }k \in K_n.$$

Consider the matrix $\mathbf{M}$ given by

$$ \mathbf{M} = \mathbf{B}(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B})^{-1}\mathbf{A}, $$

with principal minors given by $\det(\mathbf{M}_{k})$ for any $k \in P(K)$, where $P(K)$ is the power set of $K$ (the set of all subsets of $K$).

---

**Conjecture**

> I want to show that
>   $$ \det(\mathbf{M}_{k}) = \frac{1}{\Delta}\sum_{j\in \{ i \in K_n : k \subset i \}}d_j, \;\;\;\;\text{for all }k \in P(K) $$

---

**Example to clarify notation**

Suppose that $m=3$ and $n=2$. Then, from the definitions we have that

\begin{align}
P(K) =& \{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\} \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \\[3ex]
K_n =& \{\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\}\} \\[3ex]
\mathbf{A} =& \left[\begin{matrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \end{matrix}\right],  \;\;\; \mathbf{B} = \left[\begin{matrix} b_{11} & b_{12}  \\ b_{21} & b_{22}  \\ b_{31} & b_{32} \end{matrix}\right] \\[3ex]
\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B} =& \left[\begin{matrix} a_{11}b_{11}+a_{12}b_{21}+a_{13}b_{31} & a_{11}b_{12}+a_{12}b_{22}+a_{13}b_{32} \\
a_{21}b_{11}+a_{22}b_{21}+a_{23}b_{31} & a_{21}b_{12}+a_{22}b_{22}+a_{23}b_{32}\end{matrix}\right]
\end{align}

and the Cauchy-Binet formula implies

\begin{align}
\det(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}) =& \det(\mathbf{A}_{c\{1,2\}})\det(\mathbf{B}_{r\{1,2\}}) + \det(\mathbf{A}_{c\{1,3\}})\det(\mathbf{B}_{r\{1,3\}}) + \det(\mathbf{A}_{c\{2,3\}})\det(\mathbf{B}_{r\{2,3\}}) \\[2ex]
=& \det\left[\begin{matrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{matrix}\right]\det\left[\begin{matrix} b_{11} & b_{12}  \\ b_{21} & b_{22}  \end{matrix}\right] + \det\left[\begin{matrix} a_{11} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{23} \end{matrix}\right]\det\left[\begin{matrix} b_{11} & b_{12}  \\ b_{31} & b_{32} \end{matrix}\right] + \\[1ex]
 & \det\left[\begin{matrix}  a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{22} & a_{23} \end{matrix}\right]\det\left[\begin{matrix} b_{21} & b_{22}  \\ b_{31} & b_{32} \end{matrix}\right].
\end{align}

Again, using the definitions above we have that

\begin{align}
d_{\{1,2\}} \equiv & \; \det(\mathbf{A}_{c\{1,2\}})\det(\mathbf{B}_{r\{1,2\}}) \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\\[1ex]
d_{\{1,3\}} \equiv & \; \det(\mathbf{A}_{c\{1,3\}})\det(\mathbf{B}_{r\{1,3\}}) \\[1ex]
d_{\{2,3\}} \equiv & \; \det(\mathbf{A}_{c\{2,3\}})\det(\mathbf{B}_{r\{2,3\}}) \\[3ex]
\Delta \equiv & \; d_{\{1,2\}}+d_{\{1,3\}}+d_{\{2,3\}}
\end{align}

and, with some algebra, it is easy to verify that the principal minors of $\mathbf{M}$ can be written as

\begin{align}
\det(\mathbf{M}_{\{1,2\}}) =& \; \frac{1}{\Delta}\sum_{j\in \{1,2\}}d_j =\; \frac{1}{\Delta}d_{\{1,2\}} \\[2ex]
\det(\mathbf{M}_{\{1,3\}}) =& \; \frac{1}{\Delta}\sum_{j\in \{1,3\}}d_j =\; \frac{1}{\Delta}d_{\{1,3\}} \\[2ex]
\det(\mathbf{M}_{\{2,3\}}) =& \; \frac{1}{\Delta}\sum_{j\in \{2,3\}}d_j =\; \frac{1}{\Delta}d_{\{2,3\}} \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \\[2ex]
\det(\mathbf{M}_{\{3\}}) =& \; \frac{1}{\Delta}\sum_{j\in \{\{1,3\},\{2,3\}\}}d_j =\; \frac{1}{\Delta}(d_{\{1,3\}}+d_{\{2,3\}}) \\[2ex]
\det(\mathbf{M}_{\{2\}}) =& \; \frac{1}{\Delta}\sum_{j\in \{\{1,2\},\{2,3\}\}}d_j =\; \frac{1}{\Delta}(d_{\{1,2\}}+d_{\{2,3\}}) \\[2ex]
\det(\mathbf{M}_{\{1\}}) =& \; \frac{1}{\Delta}\sum_{j\in \{\{1,2\},\{1,3\}\}}d_j =\; \frac{1}{\Delta}(d_{\{1,2\}}+d_{\{1,3\}})
\end{align}

Moreover, $\det(\mathbf{M}_{\{1,2,3\}}) =0$ follows from the fact that $\det(\mathbf{M}_{\{1,2,3\}})$ is a principal minor of order $3>2=n$. All principal minors of $\mathbf{M}$ of order greater than $n$, are equal to zero, since $\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{M})=n$.

---

**Attempts at the proof using the suggestions by @darijgrinberg**

Fix $k \in P(K)$ and let $v\equiv |k|$, i.e. the number of elements in $k$. First suppose that $v \gt n$, so that $\det(\mathbf{M}_k)=0$, since $\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{M}_k)=0$, and $\{ i \in K_n : k \subset i \} = \emptyset$, so that the conjecture holds trivially.

Next, suppose that $v \le n$. What follows is tentative.

---

*Working with the definition of $\mathbf{M}_{k}$:*

By definition,

$$ \mathbf{M}_{k}=\mathbf{B}_{rk}(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B})^{-1}\mathbf{A}_{ck} $$

where $\mathbf{B}_{rk}$ and $(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B})^{-1}\mathbf{A}_{ck}$ are $(v \times n)$ and $(n \times v)$ matrices respectively. Let $L\equiv \{1,\dots,n\}$ and $L_v$ be the set of subsets of $L$ with $v$ elements, and from the Cauchy-Binet formula we have that

$$ \det(\mathbf{M}_{k})=\sum_{j \in L_v}\det\left(\mathbf{B}_{rk,cj}\right)\det\left((\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B})_{rj}^{-1}\mathbf{A}_{ck}\right), \tag1$$

and

$$ \det\left((\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B})_{rj}^{-1}\mathbf{A}_{ck}\right)=\sum_{i \in L_v}\det\left((\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B})_{rj,ci}^{-1}\right)\det\left(\mathbf{A}_{ri,ck}\right).$$

So that

$$ \det(\mathbf{M}_{k})=\sum_{i,j \in L_v}\det\left((\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B})_{rj,ci}^{-1}\right)\det\left(\mathbf{A}_{ri,ck}\right)\det\left(\mathbf{B}_{rk,cj}\right),$$

and since

$$ (\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B})^{-1}=\frac{1}{\Delta}\operatorname{adj}(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}) \implies (\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B})_{rj,ci}^{-1}=\frac{1}{\Delta}\operatorname{adj}(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B})_{rj,ci} $$

it follows that

$$ \det(\mathbf{M}_{k})=\frac{1}{\Delta^v} \sum_{i,j \in L_v}\det\left(\operatorname{adj}(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B})_{rj,ci}\right)\det\left(\mathbf{A}_{ri,ck}\right)\det\left(\mathbf{B}_{rk,cj}\right).$$

Next, for each $i,j \in L_{v}$ define $i'\equiv \{1,\dots,n\}\setminus i$ and $j'\equiv \{1,\dots,n\}\setminus j$, then it follows from [Jacobi's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280516/what-seems-to-be-the-minors-of-the-adjugate-matrix-textadja-of-a-square-m) that

$$ \det(\operatorname{adj}(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B})_{rj,ci})=(-1)^{\sigma_{ij}}\det(((\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B})^{\top})_{rj',ci'})\Delta^{v-1}=(-1)^{\sigma_{ij}}\det(\mathbf{A}_{rj'}\mathbf{B}_{ci'}) $$

where

$$ \sigma_{ij} \equiv i_{v+1}'+\cdots+i_{n}'+j_{v+1}'+\cdots+j_{n}' $$

and, therefore,

$$ \det(\mathbf{M}_{k})=\frac{1}{\Delta}\sum_{i,j \in L_{v}}(-1)^{\sigma_{ij}}\det(\mathbf{A}_{rj'}\mathbf{B}_{ci'})\det(\mathbf{A}_{ri,ck})\det(\mathbf{B}_{rk,cj}) $$

So far I haven't been able to proceed from here.

---

*Working with the conjecture equation:*

Notice that for any $j \in K_{n}$,

$$ \det((\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B})^{-1}\mathbf{A}_{cj})=\frac{1}{\Delta}\det(\mathbf{A}_{cj}), $$

so that the conjecture can be rewritten as

$$ \det(\mathbf{M}_{k}) = \sum_{j\in \{ i \in K_n : k \subset i \}}\det(\mathbf{B}_{rj})\det((\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B})^{-1}\mathbf{A}_{cj}), \tag2$$

which looks similar equation $(1)$, rewritten here for convenience

$$ \det(\mathbf{M}_{k})=\sum_{j \in L_v}\det\left(\mathbf{B}_{rk,cj}\right)\det\left((\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B})_{rj}^{-1}\mathbf{A}_{ck}\right). $$

I am not sure how to deal with the difference in the indexes between the two equations. My guess is that I will need to use a Laplace expansion to equation $(2)$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thank you!

Comment: OK, I think I know how this works, but I'm not sure when I'll have time to write up the details. (Sorry for not using your boldsymbol notations; too much to type.) For every subset $k$ of $\left\{1,2,\ldots,m\right\}$, let $B\succ k$ be the matrix obtained from $B$ by keeping only the rows indexed by the elements of $k$. Let $k\prec A$ be the matrix obtained from $A$ by keeping only the columns indexed by the elements of $k$. Let $C = \left(AB\right)^{-1}$. Then, $M_k = \left(k \prec A\right) C \left(B \succ k\right)$ (easy). Thus, you can compute $\det M_k$ using Cauchy-Binet, e.g. by ...

Comment: ... splitting $ \left(k \prec A\right) C \left(B \succ k\right)$ as $ \left(k \prec A\right) \left(C \left(B \succ k\right)\right)$. The second factor will be a column-minor of $C \left(B \succ k\right)$ of size $k$; you can move the $\det C = \Delta^{-1}$ out of it. I think the rest shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: Actually, our notations disagree: My $M_k$ is your $\mathsymbol{M}_{\text{complement of }k}$. Sorry. I think my notations are better, since my $P\left(k\right)$ then consists of $n$-element subsets, not of $m-n$-element subsets.

Comment: @darijgrinberg This is great! I can kind of see how it will work out now. Fell free to use your notation if you choose to write this up as an answer, I agree that it is more intuitive :). (I changed $P(k)$ to $F(k)$ to avoid confusion with the power set of $k$).

Comment: @darijgrinberg I think I need a little bit more of your help. I fixed some mistakes, changed the notation to follow yours and wrote down my attempt at the proof trying to follow your logic, but I got stuck pretty early on. When you have time would you mind taking a look?

Comment: Thanks for checking. My argument was wrong indeed, and your new notations are better than mine (not to mention the old ones). I think the following should be a correct argument: ...

Comment: ... Set $D = \left(AB\right)^{-1}$ and $C = DA$ (sorry for not using boldface); thus, $M = BDA = BC$. Hence, $\det M$ can be computed by Cauchy-Binet as a sum of minors of $B$ times minors of $C$, as you have done (this part, actually, is unchanged from the old argument). On the other hand, for every $n$-element subset $k$ of $K$, we have $C_{ck} = DA_{ck}$ and thus $\det\left(C_{ck}\right) = \det D \det\left(A_{ck}\right) = \Delta \det\left(A_{ck}\right)$. Hence, you can replace the $\det\left(A_{ck}\right)$ in the definition of $d_k$ by ...

Comment: ... a $\dfrac{1}{\Delta} \det\left(C_{ck}\right)$. Now I think you should get exactly the same as from Cauchy-Binet! But please check this; I am not even claiming to be right this time.

Comment: @darijgrinberg This is another great idea! I am still trying to work with it, but I've posted what I have done so far if you want to take a quick look. I apologize for bugging you so frequently and thank you for your help!

Comment: Ouch, I really got this one wrong. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I think I have a proof now. It is nowhere as simple as I believed when I wrote the comments.

I shall use a few relatively standard facts without much of a proof; I hope you know them (if not, let me know and I'll expand).

First, let me introduce my notations (which are sometimes different from
yours): Fix a commutative ring $\mathbf{k}$. Let $\mathbb{N}=\left\{
0,1,2,\ldots\right\}  $. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $\left[  n\right]  $
denote the $n$-element set $\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $. For each
$n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $I_{n}\in\mathbf{k}^{n\times n}$ be the $n\times n$
identity matrix. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and each $\left(  a_{1}
,a_{2},\ldots,a_{n}\right)  \in\mathbf{k}^{n}$, let $\operatorname*{diag}
\left(  a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n}\right)  \in\mathbf{k}^{n\times n}$ be the
diagonal $n\times n$-matrix whose diagonal entries are $a_{1},a_{2}
,\ldots,a_{n}$. I shall use the standard abbreviation $\sum\limits_{U\subseteq
V}$ (when $V$ is a set) for $\sum\limits_{U\in\mathcal{P}\left(  V\right)  }$
(where $\mathcal{P}\left(  V\right)  $ denotes the power set of $V$). For any
$n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and any $n\times m$-matrix
$A\in\mathbf{k}^{n\times m}$, we define the following submatrices of $A$:

- If $S=\left\{  s_{1}<s_{2}<\cdots<s_{k}\right\}  $ is a subset of $\left[
  n\right]  $, then $A_{rS}$ denotes the $k\times m$-matrix whose rows are the
  rows numbered $s_{1},s_{2},\ldots,s_{k}$ of $A$ (in this order).
- If $T=\left\{  t_{1}<t_{2}<\cdots<t_{\ell}\right\}  $ is a subset of
  $\left[  m\right]  $, then $A_{cT}$ denotes the $n\times\ell$-matrix whose
  columns are the columns numbered $t_{1},t_{2},\ldots,t_{\ell}$ of $A$ (in this order).
- If $S=\left\{  s_{1}<s_{2}<\cdots<s_{k}\right\}  $ is a subset of $\left[
  n\right]  $ and if $T=\left\{  t_{1}<t_{2}<\cdots<t_{\ell}\right\}  $ is a
  subset of $\left[  m\right]  $, then $A_{rS,cT}$ denotes the $k\times\ell
  $-matrix $\left(  a_{s_{i},t_{j}}\right)  _{1\leq i\leq k,\ 1\leq j\leq\ell}$,
  where $A$ is written in the form $\left(  a_{i,j}\right)  _{1\leq i\leq
  n,\ 1\leq j\leq m}$. Equivalently, $A_{rS,cT}=\left(  A_{rS}\right)
  _{cT}=\left(  A_{cT}\right)  _{rS}$.

Let me start with the standard facts that I will be using:

> **Proposition 1.** Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $A\in\mathbf{k}^{n\times n}$. Then,
>   \begin{equation}
> \det\left(  I_{n}+A\right)  =\sum\limits_{G\subseteq\left[  n\right]  }
> \det\left(  A_{rG,cG}\right)  .
> \end{equation}

Actually, Proposition 1 is a particular case of the following
more general (and probably better known) fact:

> **Proposition 1'.** Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $A \in \mathbf{k}^{n \times n}$
>   and $x \in \mathbf{k}$. Then,
>   \begin{equation}
> \det\left( xI_{n}+A\right)
> = \sum\limits_{G\subseteq\left[  n\right]  }
> \det\left(  A_{rG,cG}\right) x^{n-\left|G\right|} .
> \end{equation}

Proposition 1' is part of Corollary 6.164 in [my *Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*, in the version of 10 January 2019](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2019-01-10).
(In those notes, I'm using slightly different notations:
Namely, what I am calling $A_{rG,cG}$ here is called
$\operatorname{sub}^{w\left(G\right)}_{w\left(G\right)} A$ in my
notes.) Proposition 1 follows from Proposition 1' (applied to $x=1$).

Let me sketch a proof of Proposition 1 by handwaving, lest my
reference creates the impression that it is complicated (it is, if
one wants to have a formal proof, but intuitively it's rather
obvious):

*Hint to the proof of Proposition 1.* Write $A$ in the form $\left(
a_{i,j}\right)  _{1\leq i\leq n,\ 1\leq j\leq n}$. Compute $\det\left(
I_{n}+A\right)  $ using Laplace expansion; the result is a sum of $n!$
products. Expand each of these products further by getting rid of the
parentheses around the diagonal entries $1+a_{i,i}$. Then, combine terms which
share the same set of indices occuring under the $a$'s; the resulting sub-sums
are the $\det\left(  A_{rG,cG}\right)  $ for $G\subseteq\left[  n\right]  $.
For instance, for $n=3$, this argument goes as follows:
\begin{align}
& \det\left(  I_{n}+A\right)  \\
& = \det\left(
\begin{array}[c]{ccc}
1+a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3}\\
a_{2,1} & 1+a_{2,2} & a_{2,3}\\
a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & 1+a_{3,3}
\end{array}
\right)  \\
& = \left(  1+a_{1,1}\right)  \left(  1+a_{2,2}\right)  \left(  1+a_{3,3}
\right)  +a_{1,2}a_{2,3}a_{3,1}+a_{1,3}a_{2,1}a_{3,2} \\
& \qquad
-\left(  1+a_{1,1}\right)  a_{2,3}a_{3,2}-a_{1,2}a_{2,1}\left(
1+a_{3,3}\right)  -a_{1,3}\left(  1+a_{2,2}\right)  a_{3,1} \\
& = a_{1,1}a_{2,2}-a_{1,2}a_{2,1}+a_{1,1}a_{3,3}-a_{1,3}a_{3,1}+a_{2,2}a_{3,3} \\
& \qquad
-a_{2,3}a_{3,2}+a_{1,1}a_{2,2}a_{3,3}-a_{1,1}a_{2,3}a_{3,2}-a_{1,2}
a_{2,1}a_{3,3} \\
& \qquad
+a_{1,2}a_{3,1}a_{2,3}+a_{2,1}a_{1,3}a_{3,2}-a_{1,3}a_{2,2}a_{3,1}
+a_{1,1}+a_{2,2}+a_{3,3}+1 \\
& = \underbrace{a_{1,1}a_{2,2}a_{3,3}+a_{1,2}a_{2,3}a_{3,1}+a_{1,3}
a_{2,1}a_{3,2}-a_{1,1}a_{2,3}a_{3,2}-a_{1,2}a_{2,1}a_{3,3}-a_{1,3}
a_{2,2}a_{3,1}}_{=\det A=\det\left(  A_{r\left\{  1,2,3\right\}  ,c\left\{
1,2,3\right\}  }\right)  } \\
& \qquad
+\underbrace{a_{1,1}a_{2,2}-a_{1,2}a_{2,1}}_{=\det\left(  A_{r\left\{
1,2\right\}  ,c\left\{  1,2\right\}  }\right)  }+\underbrace{a_{1,1}
a_{3,3}-a_{1,3}a_{3,1}}_{=\det\left(  A_{r\left\{  1,3\right\}  ,c\left\{
1,3\right\}  }\right)  } \\
& \qquad
+\underbrace{a_{2,2}a_{3,3}-a_{2,3}a_{3,2}}_{=\det\left(  A_{r\left\{
2,3\right\}  ,c\left\{  2,3\right\}  }\right)  }+\underbrace{a_{1,1}}
_{=\det\left(  A_{r\left\{  1\right\}  ,c\left\{  1\right\}  }\right)  } \\
& \qquad
+\underbrace{a_{2,2}}_{=\det\left(  A_{r\left\{  2\right\}  ,c\left\{
2\right\}  }\right)  }+\underbrace{a_{3,3}}_{=\det\left(  A_{r\left\{
3\right\}  ,c\left\{  3\right\}  }\right)  }+\underbrace{1}_{=\det\left(
A_{r\varnothing,c\varnothing}\right)  } \\
& = \sum\limits_{G\subseteq\left[  n\right]  }\det\left(  A_{rG,cG}\right)  .
\end{align}

As a corollary of Proposition 1, we obtain:

> **Corollary 2.** Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $A\in\mathbf{k}^{n\times n}$. Let
>   $a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n}\in\mathbf{k}$. For each subset $G$ of $\left[
> n\right]  $, set $a_{G}=\prod_{g\in G}a_{g}\in\mathbf{k}$. Then,
>   \begin{equation}
> \det\left(  I_{n}+\operatorname*{diag}\left(  a_{1},a_{2},\ldots
> ,a_{n}\right)  A\right)  =\sum\limits_{G\subseteq\left[  n\right]  }a_{G}
> \det\left(  A_{rG,cG}\right)  .
> \end{equation}

*Proof of Corollary 2.* Let $G$ be a subset of $\left[n\right]$. Write
this subset $G$ in the form $\left\{g_1 < g_2 < \cdots < g_k\right\}$.
Then, $\prod_{i=1}^k a_{g_i} = \prod_{g\in G} a_g = a_G$.

For each $i \in \left[k\right]$, the $i$-th row of the
matrix $A_{rG, cG}$ is a subsequence of the $g_i$-th row of the matrix
$A$ (because of how $A_{rG, cG}$ is defined).

But $\operatorname*{diag}\left(  a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n}\right)  A$
is the matrix obtained from $A$ by multiplying its $i$-th row with $a_i$
for each $i \in \left[n\right]$. Hence,
$\left(\operatorname*{diag}\left(  a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n}\right)  A\right)_{rG, cG}$
is the matrix obtained from $A_{rG, cG}$ by multiplying its $i$-th row
with $a_{g_i}$ for each $i \in \left[k\right]$ (because
$G = \left\{g_1 < g_2 < \cdots < g_k\right\}$). Hence, the determinant
of this matrix
$\left(\operatorname*{diag}\left(  a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n}\right)  A\right)_{rG, cG}$
is
\begin{equation}
\left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^k a_{g_i}\right) \det\left(A_{rG, cG}\right) .
\end{equation}
In other words,
\begin{align}
\det\left(\left(\operatorname*{diag}\left(  a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n}\right)  A\right)_{rG, cG}\right)
& = \underbrace{\left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^k a_{g_i}\right)}_{= a_G} \det\left(A_{rG, cG}\right)
\\
& = a_G \det\left(A_{rG, cG}\right) .
\label{darij.eq.0}
\tag{1}
\end{align}

Now, forget that we fixed $G$. We thus have proven that \eqref{darij.eq.0} holds
for each subset $G$ of $\left[n\right]$.

Now, Proposition 1 (applied to
$\operatorname*{diag}\left(  a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n}\right)  A$ instead of
$A$) yields
\begin{align}
& \det\left(  I_{n}+\operatorname*{diag}\left(  a_{1},a_{2},\ldots
,a_{n}\right)  A\right) \\
& = \sum\limits_{G\subseteq\left[  n\right]  }
\det\left(\left(\operatorname*{diag}\left(  a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n}\right)  A\right)_{rG, cG}\right) \\
& = \sum\limits_{G\subseteq\left[  n\right]  }a_{G}
\det\left(  A_{rG,cG}\right)
\end{align}
(by \eqref{darij.eq.0}). This proves Corollary 2. $\blacksquare$

> **Proposition 3.** Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Let
>   $A\in\mathbf{k}^{n\times m}$ and $B\in\mathbf{k}^{m\times n}$. Then,
>   \begin{equation}
> \det\left(  I_{n}+AB\right)  =\det\left(  I_{m}+BA\right)  .
> \end{equation}

Proposition 3 is known as [Sylvester's determinant theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_determinant_theorem) (the link goes to a Wikipedia article which contains a proof); it also appears [on
math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17831/sylvesters-determinant-identity) (again with proofs, this time more readable). $\blacksquare$

Finally, let me state the Cauchy-Binet formula in appropriate language:

> **Theorem 4.** Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $A\in
> \mathbf{k}^{m\times n}$ and $B\in\mathbf{k}^{n\times m}$. Then,
>   \begin{equation}
> \det\left(  AB\right)  =\sum\limits_{\substack{J\subseteq\left[  n\right]
> ;\\\left\vert J\right\vert =m}}\det\left(  A_{cJ}\right)  \det\left(
> B_{rJ}\right)  .
> \end{equation}

Now, let me state my favorite version of your claim:

> **Theorem 5.** Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $B\in
> \mathbf{k}^{m\times n}$ and $C\in\mathbf{k}^{n\times m}$ be such that
>   $CB=I_{n}$. Let $M=BC$. Then, every subset $G$ of $\left[  m\right]  $ satisfies
>   \begin{equation}
> \det\left(  M_{rG,cG}\right)  =\sum\limits_{\substack{J\subseteq\left[
> m\right]  ;\\\left\vert J\right\vert =n;\\G\subseteq J}}\det\left(
> B_{rJ}\right)  \det\left(  C_{cJ}\right)  .
> \end{equation}

How to get from Theorem 5 to your conjecture? Notice that my $G$ and $J$ are
your $k$ and $j$. Set $C=\left(  AB\right)  ^{-1}A$ and observe that
$CB=I_{n}$ and $M=BC$; furthermore, use $C=\left(  AB\right)  ^{-1}A$ to
observe that $C_{cJ}=\left(  \left(  AB\right)  ^{-1}A\right)  _{cJ}=\left(
AB\right)  ^{-1}A_{cJ}$ and thus $\det\left(  C_{cJ}\right)  =\underbrace{\det
\left(  \left(  AB\right)  ^{-1}\right)  }_{=\dfrac{1}{\Delta}}\det\left(
A_{cJ}\right)  =\dfrac{1}{\Delta}\det\left(  A_{cJ}\right)  $, so that my
$\det\left(  B_{rJ}\right)  \det\left(  C_{cJ}\right)  $ is your $\dfrac
{1}{\Delta}d_{J}$. Now, Theorem 5 quickly turns into your claim. (I don't know
how real the extra generality of Theorem 5 is, though; it does seem harder to
derive it back from your conjecture, at least.)

*Proof of Theorem 5.* Let $\mathbf{m}$ be the polynomial ring $\mathbf{k}
\left[  x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{m}\right]  $ over $\mathbf{k}$ in $m$ commuting
indeterminates $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{m}$. Then, $\mathbf{k}$ is a subring of
$\mathbf{m}$, so that $\mathbf{k}^{n\times m}\subseteq\mathbf{m}^{n\times m}$
and $\mathbf{k}^{m\times n}\subseteq\mathbf{m}^{m\times n}$. Define a matrix
$\widetilde{B}\in\mathbf{m}^{m\times n}$ by $\widetilde{B}
=\operatorname*{diag}\left(  1+x_{1},1+x_{2},\ldots,1+x_{m}\right)  \cdot B$.
For each subset $G$ of $\left[  m\right]  $, set $x_{G}=\prod_{g\in G}x_{g}
\in\mathbf{m}$.

Every subset $J$ of $\left[  m\right]  $ satisfies
\begin{align}
\det\left(  \widetilde{B}_{rJ}\right)  =\left(  \sum
\limits_{G\subseteq J}x_{G}\right)  \det\left(  B_{rJ}\right)  .
\label{darij.eq.1}
\tag{2}
\end{align}

*Proof of \eqref{darij.eq.1}:* Let $J$ be a subset of $\left[  m\right]  $. Write $J$ in
the form $\left\{  j_{1}<j_{2}<\cdots<j_{k}\right\}  $. Now, $\widetilde{B}
=\operatorname*{diag}\left(  1+x_{1},1+x_{2},\ldots,1+x_{m}\right)  \cdot B$;
in other words, $\widetilde{B}$ is the result of multiplying the $i$-th row of
$B$ with $1+x_{i}$ for each $i\in\left[  m\right]  $. Hence, $\widetilde{B}
_{rJ}$ is the result of multiplying the $i$-th row of $\widetilde{B}$ with
$1+x_{j_{i}}$ for each $i\in\left[  k\right]  $. Therefore,
\begin{align}
\det\left(  \widetilde{B}_{rJ}\right)  =\left(  \prod_{i\in\left[  k\right]
}\left(  1+x_{j_{i}}\right)  \right)  \det\left(  B_{rJ}\right)  .
\end{align}
But since $\prod_{i\in\left[  k\right]  }\left(  1+x_{j_{i}}\right)
=\sum\limits_{G\subseteq J}x_{G}$ (this is a classical identity), this
rewrites as
\begin{align}
\det\left(  \widetilde{B}_{rJ}\right)  =\left(  \sum\limits_{G\subseteq J}
x_{G}\right)  \det\left(  B_{rJ}\right)  .
\end{align}
Thus, \eqref{darij.eq.1} is proven.

Note that
\begin{align}
\widetilde{B}
&= \underbrace{\operatorname*{diag}\left(  1+x_{1},1+x_{2}
,\ldots,1+x_{m}\right)  }_{=I_{m}+\operatorname*{diag}\left(  x_{1}
,x_{2},\ldots,x_{m}\right)  }\cdot B \\
& = \left(  I_{m}+\operatorname*{diag}\left(  x_{1},x_{2},\ldots
,x_{m}\right)  \right)  B .
\label{darij.eq.2}
\tag{3}
\end{align}

On the other hand, Corollary 2 (applied to $\mathbf{m}$, $m$, $M$, $x_{i}$ and
$x_{G}$ instead of $\mathbf{k}$, $n$, $A$, $a_{i}$ and $a_{G}$) shows that
\begin{align}
\det\left(  I_{m}+\operatorname*{diag}\left(  x_{1},x_{2}
,\ldots,x_{m}\right)  M\right)  =\sum\limits_{G\subseteq\left[  m\right]
}x_{G} \det\left(  M_{rG,cG}\right)  .
\label{darij.eq.3}
\tag{4}
\end{align}

But Proposition 3 (applied to $\mathbf{m}$, $C$ and $\operatorname*{diag}
\left(  x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{m}\right)  B$ instead of $\mathbf{k}$, $A$ and
$B$) yields
\begin{align}
& \det\left(  I_{n}+C\operatorname*{diag}\left(  x_{1},x_{2},\ldots
,x_{m}\right)  B\right)  \\
& = \det\left(  I_{m}+\operatorname*{diag}\left(  x_{1},x_{2},\ldots
,x_{m}\right)  \underbrace{BC}_{=M}\right)  \\
& =\det\left(  I_{m}+\operatorname*{diag}\left(  x_{1},x_{2},\ldots
,x_{m}\right)  M\right)  \\
& = \sum\limits_{G\subseteq\left[  m\right]  }x_{G}\det\left(  M_{rG,cG}\right)
\end{align}
(by \eqref{darij.eq.3}).
Hence,
\begin{align}
& \sum\limits_{G\subseteq\left[  m\right]  }x_{G}\det\left(  M_{rG,cG}\right) \\
& = \det\left(  \underbrace{I_{n}}_{=CB}+C\operatorname*{diag}\left(
x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{m}\right)  B\right)  \\
& = \det\left(  \underbrace{CB+C\operatorname*{diag}\left(  x_{1},x_{2}
,\ldots,x_{m}\right)  B}_{=C\left(  I_{m}+\operatorname*{diag}\left(
x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{m}\right)  \right)  B}\right)  \\
& =\det\left(  C\underbrace{\left(  I_{m}+\operatorname*{diag}\left(
x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{m}\right)  \right)  B}_{\substack{=\widetilde{B}
\\\text{(by \eqref{darij.eq.2})}}}\right)  \\
& =\det\left(  C\widetilde{B}\right)  =\sum\limits_{\substack{J\subseteq\left[
m\right]  ;\\\left\vert J\right\vert =n}}\det\left(  C_{cJ}\right)
\underbrace{\det\left(  \widetilde{B}_{rJ}\right)  }_{\substack{=\left(
\sum\limits_{G\subseteq J}x_{G}\right)  \det\left(  B_{rJ}\right)  \\\text{(by
\eqref{darij.eq.1})}}} \\
& \qquad \qquad
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\text{by Theorem 4, applied to $\mathbf{m}$, $m$, $n$, $C$ and $\widetilde{B}$}
\\
\text{instead of $\mathbf{k}$, $n$, $m$, $A$ and $B$}
\end{array}
\right) \\
& =\sum\limits_{\substack{J\subseteq\left[  m\right]  ;\\\left\vert
J\right\vert =n}}\det\left(  C_{cJ}\right)  \left(  \sum\limits_{G\subseteq
J}x_{G}\right)  \det\left(  B_{rJ}\right)  \\
& = \sum\limits_{\substack{J\subseteq\left[  m\right]  ;\\\left\vert
J\right\vert =n}}\left(  \sum\limits_{G\subseteq J}x_{G}\right)  \det\left(
B_{rJ}\right)  \det\left(  C_{cJ}\right)  \\
& = \sum\limits_{G\subseteq\left[  m\right]  }\left(  \sum
\limits_{\substack{J\subseteq\left[  m\right]  ;\\\left\vert J\right\vert
=n;\\G\subseteq J}}\det\left(  B_{rJ}\right)  \det\left(  C_{cJ}\right)
\right)  x_{G} .
\end{align}
This is an equality between two polynomials in $\mathbf{m}=\mathbf{k}\left[
x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{m}\right]  $. Comparing the coefficients of the
monomials before $x_{G}$ on both sides of this equality, we conclude that
\begin{align}
\det\left(  M_{rG,cG}\right)  =\sum\limits_{\substack{J\subseteq\left[
m\right]  ;\\\left\vert J\right\vert =n;\\G\subseteq J}}\det\left(
B_{rJ}\right)  \det\left(  C_{cJ}\right) \qquad
\text{for every subset $G$ of $\left[ m\right]  $} .
\end{align}
This proves Theorem 5. $\blacksquare$

Comment: This is amazing! I can't thank you enough! I'm still digesting the proof, but if you don't mind I have a quick clarifying question: in Theorem 4 shouldn't the summation be over $J \subseteq [n]$ with the additional constraint that $J$ have $m$ elements?

Comment: Fixed -- thank you! (and thanks for the interesting question, too.)